# How you say 捅人牛 in Hokkien?

Tags: translation

How do you say 捅人牛 in hokkien? In pinyin, please.

Comment: I wonder if one could use pinyin for hokkien since pinyin are designed for Mandarin. Instead of pinyin, you could ask for Romanized words for the pronunciation.

Comment: What is 捅人牛 meant to mean? Searching the [Holodict](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/index.html) doesn't give this as a set Hokkien phrase.

Answer (score 2):

[Hokkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokkien) is a group of Southern Min dialects spoken throughout Southeastern China, Taiwan and Southeast Asia, and by other overseas Chinese.

[泉漳片](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%89%E6%BC%B3%E7%89%87)也稱為泉漳閩南語、泉漳話、漳泉話、閩台片，是閩南語最大的一簇方言分片，也是最具有影響力和代表性的閩南語。狹義的閩南語指的是閩台片的閩南語。英語通常稱為 Hokkien。泉漳片緣起於中國福建南部，除分布於閩南本土，也廣泛流行於臺灣、新加坡、馬來西亞、菲律賓等許多閩南移民與其後裔的居住地。

The following information belongs to [Taiwanese Hokkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Hokkien) ([臺灣閩南語](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E8%A9%B1)).

[《臺灣閩南語**常用詞**辭典》](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/default.jsp) can show the relevant information. But this site does not have a link to each page, so the screenshots are given below.

Input 捅 in the field and press [Enter]. The pronunciation is thóng.

However, this is 統 in Mandarin, such as 統計 or 系統. So, we can not directly check 捅.

Assuming 捅人牛 means 撞人的牛, we should look up 撞 in Mandarin. Therefore, enter 撞, select 對應華語, and press [Enter].

[image: t1.png]

The pronunciation is tōng, like 通 in Mandarin.

As far as I know, the 撞 of 撞到 in Hokkien is not so pronounced, but like 弄 in Mandarin. Fortunately, at the end of 釋義 1 in the above table shows 挵. Click the link to get the following table.

[image: t2.png]

The pronunciation of 挵 is lòng. 釋義 1 also shows the meaning of 碰撞 (to collide).

人 also has two kinds of pronunciation.

[image: t3.png]

The pronunciation of 人 in 人類, 人情 or 軍人 is jîn。

[image: t4.png]

The pronunciation of 人 of 做人, 別人 and 好人 is lâng。

As far as I know, the Hokkien pronunciation of 人 in 撞人 is lâng, like 郎 in Mandarin.

牛 also has two kinds of pronunciation, gû and giû。

[image: t5.png]

As far as I know, the vast majority of people read gû, like the second tone of ⻣.

Conclusion：

If 捅人牛 means 撞人牛, the pronunciation should be lòng lâng gû。

Answer (score 1):

Based on your words, the pronunciation for every word would be:

捅 【thóng】

人 【lâng】

牛 【gû】

Please refer to: [Southern Min Language Dictionary of Republic of China 中華民國台灣區閩南語字典](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/index.html)

And do remember, Hokkien, also known as 福建話 (泉州片), is one of the principal branches of Southern Min (閩南語). The dictionary which I have suggested to you is Southern Min (not really Hokkien). Something like inheritance, Hokkien is a child while Southern Min is his father, they are not really the same, but they are similar.

Hope you enjoy this.

Answer (score -1):

[捅](http://www.syndict.com/w.php?item=hak&place=bo_luo&word=%E6%8D%85)[人](http://www.syndict.com/w.php?item=hak&place=bo_luo&word=%E4%BA%BA)[牛](http://www.syndict.com/w.php?item=hak&place=bo_luo&word=%E7%89%9B)

tung31-ngin11-ngiu11

You can use the sound button on each of the three webpages above to hear the correct pronunciation.

Comment: I wonder why you are linking a Hakka source for a question about Hokkien...